# Fock-space-related combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I don't really know how to approach a combinatorial problem arising from the physics context. Here's the setting. The state of a bosonic system in ${(1+1)}$ dimensions is described by a vector of the form
$$
|\psi\rangle = |n_1^{m_1},n_2^{m_2},\ldots,n_N^{m^{N}}\rangle
\quad,\quad
n_j=\pm1,\pm2,\cdots,\pm\Lambda\quad.
$$
This states contains $m_1$ particles of momentum $n_1$, $m_2$ particles of momentum $n_2$, etc.

The momentum and of this state is
$$
P = \sum_{j=1}^N n_j m_j
\quad.
$$

I would like to estimate the total number of states having the property
$$
P = 0 \quad.
$$
Importantly, a need a very ROUGH estimate of the upper bound. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are allowed values of $m_j$ when $n_j = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Should've excluded $0$ from the list of allowed momenta (technically, such states exist but we can exclude them for simplicity)

Comment: Two more questions (to be sure I'm getting it right): $\color{red}{1.}$ Do $n_j$ need to be pairwise distinct (i.e. should it be $i \neq j \Rightarrow n_i \neq n_j$)? $\color{red}{2.}$ Does a permutation affect a state (i.e. if we exchange, say, $n_1 \leftrightarrow n_2$ and simultaneously $m_1 \leftrightarrow m_2$, is it the same state or we should count these as two different ones)?

Comment: (After that I think I'm almost ready...)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Yes, the convention is that $n$'s are distinct. A state $|1^2,1^3\rangle$ would simply be written as $|1^5\rangle$ ($5$ particles with the momentum $1$). The order in which $n_j$'s go is conventional, so interchanging does not affect anything.

Comment: I expect that the asymptotics should be smth like the number of partitions of an integer.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Just realized that the correct statement of the problem is different, please see the current version. So sorry about your time :(

Comment: Sorry for a period of silence in turn. But now $m_j\mapsto m_j m$ (with any positive integer $m$) again gives an infinitude of the number of solutions.